# Try to convert in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
    $("#menu").click(function () {
        var x = document.getElementById("sideMenu");
        var y = document.getElementById("content");

        if (x.style.display === "none") {
            x.style.display = "block";
            y.style.marginLeft = "320px";
        } else {
            x.style.display = "none";
            y.style.marginLeft = "0px";
        }
    });
```

Here is my java script code now I want to convert this into react.

Comment: Create a react project, and bind the element to a onClick in the JSX, apply styles from a useState and you can change them

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are gonna set `onClick` on your `#menu`:

```
const x = document.getElementById("sideMenu");
const y = document.getElementById("content");

const handleClick = () => {
            if (x.style.display === "none") {
            x.style.display = "block";
            y.style.marginLeft = "320px";
        } else {
            x.style.display = "none";
            y.style.marginLeft = "0px";
        }
      }
.
.
.

<div id="menu" onClick={handleClick}> something </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you have to create components each of dom elements and render them conditionally. Looks something like this.

```
function Menu() {
    function clickHandler() {
     // your logic
    }
    <div id="menu" onClick={clickHandler}>YOUR MARKUP</div>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how , it would look in react .

```
import React from 'react'
const Menu = ()=>{
    var x = document.getElementById("sideMenu");
    var y = document.getElementById("content");
  const handleClick = ()=>{
    if (x.style.display === "none") {
        x.style.display = "block";
        y.style.marginLeft = "320px";
    } else {
        x.style.display = "none";
        y.style.marginLeft = "0px";
    }
  }

  return (
    <div id="menu" onClick={handleClick}>Menu</div>
  )
}
```

Comment: My sideMenu element is in another component, so how I can get sideMenu element? And also content from other component...

Comment: React will take care of it ... as far as the components are present inside DOM . It will find that node .

Comment: If you find this helpful , then do upvote and accept the answer, as others can find it more easily .

Comment: Now it works. What if I want to more style?

Comment: @M.SHA. you can just create `Style.css` and `import './Style.css'` to your file

Comment: I want to add more css like this (y.style.marginLeft = "320px";)